# How can I use Storage account name and container name environment independently

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

For my application I have created different environment resource in my azure portal, I have a storage account, container and AppService for each environment (devStorageAccount, testStorageAccount, devContainer, testContainer).

So how can I use this account name and accesskey in my code with environment independently? Is there any approach to use this in common way? Will it take relevant name and keys based on environment?

Comment: I think what you want is azure app service deployment solts. So have a look of this doc:[1.azure web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) [2.azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots)

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps service (https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is azure app service deployment solts.

You can have a look of these docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots

What you need to notice is the plan you choose decide how many solts you can use.